# Flutter Build Error (One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.)

Tags: flutter, apple-m1

I am unable to run flutter app for ios simulator
device MAC AIR M1
simulator iphone 13 ios 15.4
Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.3, on macOS 12.3 21E230 darwin-arm, locale en-IN)
error

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           11.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[57109]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libamsupport.dylib (0x1e3a22098) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1060242c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[57109]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libamsupport.dylib (0x1e3a220e8) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x106024318). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[57109]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerRestoreInfoHelper is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1e3a21eb0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1060244f8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[57109]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareAggregateRequestCreator is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1e3a21f00) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x106024548). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[57109]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareRequestCreator is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1e3a21f50) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x106024598). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[57109]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABFile is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1e3a21fa0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1060245e8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[57109]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareCopier is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1e3a21ff0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x106024638). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[57109]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABSubfile is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1e3a22040) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x106024688). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/b7/hgz_bln978v50z_4np3bb3ww0000gn/T/flutter_tools.wYYYjO/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirOOWshA/temporary_xcresult_bundle


    Failed to package /Users/yashc/Desktop/t.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/b7/hgz_bln978v50z_4np3bb3ww0000gn/T/flutter_tools.wYYYjO/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirOOWshA/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
```

i am trying to build new project that also fails .
showing same above error
Thankyou

Comment: Have you been able to fix this issue? I'm getting the same problem on the latest flutter version. I had to downgrade to 2.8.1 to work still.

Answer (score 0):

Apple owns this screwup with the man command (and some others) spewing duplicate class implementation gibberish. To avoid this, I have implemented in my ~/.zshrc file, the following alias:

alias man='man "$@" 2> /dev/null'﻿
﻿

and then man provides quick, clean output by redirecting all of the nonsense to the bit bucket.

For that alias to take effect in the same Terminal session, do the following, otherwise a new Terminal session will pick it up:

source ~/.zshrc
﻿